# How to save state of all apps, switch to another state and come back later?

Tags: macos

I am working on multiple projects on my Mac. I want to save the state of all windows and close them; this will let me work on another project. When I want to come back to my first project, I should be able to open the "context" and get all the windows back again.

Is this possible?

For example, if am working on an Android app, I will have Android Studio, Safari (with AndroidDeveloper site and other stuff open), Terminal, etc. open. Now, suppose I have to do something with my WebGL project, so I want to close everything and save the state. I fix whatever in the WebGL project and comeback to my app. So I want to open Android Studio + Safari etc., again.

Comment: What apps for work are you talking about?  it is unclear to me. You didnt even add other tags.

Comment: I am talking about any app. For example, if am working on an Android app, I will have Android Studio, Safari (with AndroidDeveloper site and other stuff open), Terminal, etc. open. Now, suppose I have to do something with my WebGL project, so I want to close everything and save the state. I fix whatever in the WebGL project and comeback to my app. So I want to open Android Studio + other stuff again.

Comment: If file permissions don't cause trouble you can have multiple user accounts, all admins. (search Fast user switching Mac ) However, keeping desktops separate helps, but it cannot reclaim resources used by supposedly dormant apps. BTW, I cannot think of other tags either.

Comment: Have you considered using Spaces?